# Cómo cambiar dirección de logs Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, login, dominio, log

Subí una app hecha en **Laravel** a un host, al entrar a la dirección, dice:

> No existe un directorio en `"/var/www/html/agenda/storage/logs"` y no se pudo crear: sistema de archivos de solo lectura.

Esa ruta si existe en mi ambiente de desarrollo, pero en el host no.

> **¿Cómo puedo cambiar la ruta donde se guarda ese log?**

Comment: El servidor tendría que tener permisos de escritura en el directorio storage y en bootstrap/cache. Te sugiero que arregles eso en vez de cambiar de lugar los logs

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya he realizado esa configuración, pero el error continúa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día.
Muchas gracias por el apoyo, ya he resultó el problema, solo eliminé manualmente los archivos de caché (Bootstrap/Caché) solo deje el .gitignore después de eso la aplicación funcionó de manera correcta, de nuevo gracias !!!